# mounting a freedos virtual box in Debian

Tags: debian, virtualbox, freedos

I have installed virtualbox in Debian 9.  Then, I installed FreeDOS in the virtual box folling the tutorial in http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/VirtualBox_-_Chapter_6.  I have installed the libguestfs-tools and fuse.

Now, when I run 
guestmount -a freeDOS.vhd -m /dev/sda1 /data/freeDOS

I get this
guestmount: access: freeDOS.vhd: No such file or directory

the command
virt-filesystems --long --filesystems -a /data/freeDOS/freeDOS.vhd

gives this
Name       Type        VFS   Label        Size       Parent
/dev/sda1  filesystem  vfat  FREEDOS2016  104752640  -

Any help on how to mount the freeDOS vhd to share it with Debian?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you considered https://www.dosbox.com/ ? There is a Debian version that might well suit your needs.

Comment: If your question has typo(s), [edit] it and correct them.

Answer (score 1):

First command says freeDOS.vdi and second freeDOS.vhd

Comment: yes. sorry. it should say guestmount -a freeDOS.vhd -m /dev/sda1 /data/freeDOS

Comment: welp I thought that was the source of your problem?

Comment: no. \i am afraid the problem still remains.  for some reason guestmount does not recognize the *.vhd.  I have read some forums and it seems that the guestmount mount *.img.  But the freedos tutorial says the it can mount *.vhd

Answer (score 0):

1. Load nbd module
   modprobe nbd max_part=16
2. Map vhd/vdi to system

   qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 image.qcow2
3. View partition in vhd

   fdisk -l
4. Mount the partition you want

   mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt

Video step by step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIpvNoJmVRs